# Как инициализировать базу данных?

Tags: mysql

При установке любой CMS(Drupal, WP, Joomla) происходит инициализация БД с необходимой структурой, какой механизм отвечает за этот процесс?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В каждой CMS и в шаблонах сайта (форума) есть файлы со скриптами создания и заполнения БД. Они принимают на вход данные подключения к СУБД в виде первичного диалога. После заполнения либо деактивируются, либо просят юзера удалить эти файлы вручную.

В каждом случае это разные файлы (имена, расположения, функции).

Comment: А скрипты написаны на PHP?

Comment: Обычно - да (если CMS на PHP)